# Is there a standard lightning event to show custom component value change to parent?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm working on an input component, and would like to notify the parent when the value changes

```
<!-- c:parent -->
<c:myInput onChange="{!c.handler}" />
```

But to do so, I need an event type to register in my input component...

```
<!-- c:myInput -->
<aura:registerEvent name="onChange" type="???"/>
```

Is there a standard event I can use to this effect or do I have no other choice than to create my own onChange event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default type of a "value change" notification is the `aura:valueChange` event. Unfortunately, you can't use it:

```
<!-- compiler error here -->
<!-- Cannot fire event of type: markup://aura:valueChange: Source -->
<aura:registerEvent name="onchange" type="aura:valueChange" />
```

So yes, if you want to be able to "fire your own event", you'd have to use a custom event, as we can't fire system events.

According to the documentation, you're supposed to be able to extend the default aura:valueChange event, or register use of it directly, since it is global, but unfortunately, neither are currently allowed by compiler (see above for registerEvent):

```
<!-- Failed to save valueChange.evt: Event markup://c:valueChange cannot extend markup://aura:valueChange: Source -->
<aura:event extends="aura:valueChange" ...
```

Ultimately, a custom event is the only viable method at this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change handle to keep track of data changes.

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.numItems}" action="{!c.itemsChange}"/>
```

The value attribute sets the component attribute that the change handler tracks.

The action attribute sets the client-side controller action to invoke when the attribute value changes.

A component can have multiple  tags to detect changes to different attributes.

[Detecting Data Changes with Change Handlers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_data_change.htm)